# Citation undefined

Tags: bibliographies

i'm trying to build my bibliography. i'm using Texstudio & jabref. 
The first book that i added to jabref was with the ISBN code - worked fine. 
the second book was found using google scholar in jabref, when i'm trying to cite it

```
\cite{bookname}
```

i get a question mark near the text

```
[?]
```

followed with error in the log

```
Citation "bookkname" on page undefined
```

i'm new with latex so please be patience with me... if more info is needed i will provide it
thx

Comment: Looks like http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/63852/question-mark-instead-of-citation-number to me

Comment: Check the spelling. Your error message has `bookkname` but you've written `\cite{bookname}` in your question, which doesn't match.

Comment: Nicola , sorry it is just missed typing.

Comment: Joseph your link doesn't help so much , i think i'm using bibtex and not biblatex , which isn't explained